# Python virtual environment (venv) user packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

Does the concept of user packages exist for `venv`? I activated a venv, and tried:

```
$ pip3 install --user times2
```

However, `pip3 list` does not show the package, and `pip3 uninstall times2` shows:

```
$ pip3 uninstall times2
Skipping times2 as it is not installed.
```

EDIT: adding a complete printout:

```
rishai@mbp157:~$ python3 -m venv sw/venvsandbox2
rishai@mbp157:~$
rishai@mbp157:~$
rishai@mbp157:~$ source sw/venvsandbox2/bin/activate
(venvsandbox2) rishai@mbp157:~$
(venvsandbox2) rishai@mbp157:~$
(venvsandbox2) rishai@mbp157:~$ pip3 list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.0.3
setuptools 40.8.0
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(venvsandbox2) rishai@mbp157:~$ pip3 install --user times2
Collecting times2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/bc/22dbef03a9194dd4a7465a5a0be4b05f372fbdea7e9c59f0fd0caff8ca6f/times2-0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil (from times2)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz (from times2)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/76/46d697698a143e05f77bec5a526bf4e56a0be61d63425b68f4ba553b51f2/pytz-2019.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil->times2)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, pytz, times2
Successfully installed python-dateutil-2.8.0 pytz-2019.2 six-1.12.0 times2-0.8
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(venvsandbox2) rishai@mbp157:~$ pip3 list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.0.3
setuptools 40.8.0
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(venvsandbox2) rishai@mbp157:~$ python3
Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 18:13:23)
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import times2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'times2'
>>>
```

Comment: A venv is just a folder on your machine, so is a user directory. So I'm not sure I understand what the point of trying to do both is

Comment: If you are on a server, using --user will only install it in the user directory as otherwise, you may not have the permission to use sudo  to install everything in the root directory.

Comment: @ParijatBhatt your observation is correct - it did install in the user directory. However, inside the venv, I can't access it, i.e. `import times2` produces an error. This seems rather counter-intuitive - I can install user packages in venv, but I can't access them in venv. Strange.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error here?

Comment: @ParijatBhatt added

Comment: @alkasm That's a good point. The reason I was asking is because I was reading https://janakiev.com/til/jupyter-virtual-envs/, and the instructions state "First, you need to activate your virtual environment. Next, install ipykernel which provides the IPython kernel for Jupyter:
pip install --user ipykernel". I now think `--user` should not be there.

Comment: I think you are slightly misunderstanding what is happening in that tutorial. The ipython kernel is what's being installed into your user directory. Then, you are linking the kernel to a virtual environment. This way, you don't have a new ipython kernel for every single virtual environment you use. I actually didn't know that was possible until seeing that link, which is pretty cool. Read that section of the tutorial again more carefully and I think it will be clear!

Comment: @alkasm I'm not seeing the step to link the kernel (installed in user directory) to the venv. In fact, trying it now, the second step `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=myenv` fails for me, with an error saying `ipykernel` cannot be found.

Comment: Oh, hm. I see, I guess I read the article wrong. Anyways, [here's the official docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html) for `ipykernel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It surely exist and you made it happen.

You passed that `--user` argument to pip and so instructed it to "place the provided packages in the user directory instead of the default".

The default in your case is inside the activated virtual environment and if you hadn't activated it prior to call then it would have been installed in the system directory.

Deactivate your environment and `pip3 freeze` will show the package, `sudo pip3 freeze` won't show it and in GNU/Linux `locate times2` will find it somewhere bellow `~/local/`.

Comment: hi ipaleka, "The default in your case is inside the activated virtual environment" - I did activate prior to installation. You seem to say it should have been installed, but I can't use it in my venv, i.e. `import times2` produces an error.

Comment: You installed it in the user directory **instead** of inside the activated venv.

Comment: I see - so pip's `install --user` doesn't care if you're inside (aka activated) a venv or not, it will install in the user directory - am I right?